# Python get a "sub" 2d list from bigger 2d list?

Tags: python, list, grid, 2d

How would you get a 2d sublist from a bigger 2d list?

```
gridx = 10
gridy = 16

grid = [[0]*gridx for i in range(gridy)]
subgrid = None
# I want to get a subgrid given an x,y grid origin (bottom-left) and x,y subgrid size
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to slice your 2D list at the limits x1, y1, x2, y2 you can do:

```
def getsubgrid(x1, y1, x2, y2, grid):
    return [item[x1:x2] for item in grid[y1:y2]]
```

for example:

```
grid = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        [11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19],
        [21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29],
        [31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39],
        [41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49],
        [51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59]]

print getsubgrid(3,2,5,4,grid)

#prints [[24, 25], [34, 35]]
```

Comment: This example solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your grid is stored in a list of lists? That is:

```
primary list: [ * * * * * * ]
second item:    * * * * * *
```

If so, your answer is a walk across these lists, from your start point, to your endpoint.

```
sublist = []
for x in range(startx, endx):
     sublist.append(oldlist[x][starty:endy])
```

Comment: TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple

Comment: @joaquin oops, that was supposed to be a colon. Fixed it.